# Looking for a deleted post

Tags: discussion, specific-question

If you're looking for a deleted post that you would be able to see if you had the URL (e.g. if it's your own post or if you have enough points to view deleted posts), here's a place where you can make a case to the diamond moderation team to request the URL. This may not be necessary for seeing your *own* deleted posts, now that there's a new feature made available that allows you to click on "deleted posts" when looking at your own profile, but since that feature is new, it might also have bugs, so this thread might  be useful in that case too.

Answer (score 0):

A user was awarded the Disciplined badge on 7 December 2022:

[image]

But nothing seems to have been deleted on 7 December 2022:

[image]

I managed to put on my detective hat, and noticed that [their profile](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/users/4831/peter) says they have 41 rep, despite no questions or answers, which lead me to discover that the user [earned](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/help/badges/2/student?userid=4831) the student badge for [this (now deleted, so only people with enough points will see it) question](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/8961/5); and bingo, this was the question deleted on 4 December, but it didn't show up in the "recently deleted"  list in the moderator tools. Possibly a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) for deleted posts associated with *closed* questions? I also thought that users lose their rep associated with deleted posts, which doesn't seem to have happened this time.